# How to split a column in two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, hive

I have an issue with a table called "movies". I found the date and the movie title are both in the title column. As shown in the picture:

[image: Sample]

I don't know how to deal with this kind of issues. So, I tried to play with this code to make it similar to MySQL codes but I didn't work anyways.

```
DataFrame(row.str.split(' ',-1).tolist(),columns = ['title','date'])
```

How do I split it in two columns (title, date)?

Comment: You can use STRING_SPLIT if your SQLServer version is up to date. You can also use substring if the "date" is always a year I parens. Unfortunately, I don't think there's a great solution. You're not gonna have any effective use of an index or UDF that I can think of for this job, and you'll have to assume something about your data, regardless.

Comment: @dylanthelion This is not a SQL Server question AFAIK.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen That's right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling and searching I was able to build this command which works perfectly.

```
select
   translate(substr(title,0,length(title) -6) ,'', '') as title,
   translate(substr(title, -5) ,')', '') as date
from movies;
```

Thanks for the people who answered too!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then we can try using `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE(title, '^(.*)\\s\\(.*$', '$1') AS title,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(title, '^.*\\s\\((\\d+)\\)$', '$1') AS date
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

Here is a general regex pattern which can match your title strings:

```
^.*\s\((\d+)\)$
```

Explanation:

```
^            from the start of the string
    (.*)\s   match and capture anything, up to the last space
    \(       match a literal opening parenthesis
    (\d+)    match and capture the year (any number of digits)
    \)       match a literal closing parenthesis
$            end of string
```

Comment: Thank you Tim, this great answer works well. Could you please explain how ('^(.*)\\s\\(.*$') and (*\\s\\((\\d+)\\)$') works? I might need it in other things.

Comment: @MohammadAlamri I have added an explanation for the regex pattern.  If you want to explore the regex in isolation, then I suggest using [Regex 101](http://www.regex101.com).

Answer (score 1):

I would simply do:

```
select left(title, length(title) - 7) as title,
       replace(right(title, 5) ,')', '') as year
```

Regular expressions seem like overkill for this logic.

In Hive, you need to use `substr()` for this:

```
select substr(title, 1, length(title) - 7) as title,
       substr(title, length(title) - 5, 4) as year
```

Comment: Well, I tried it but it didn't work. even I tried to make some changes, but no output.

Comment: The problem I got is : "Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Line 0:-1 Invalid function 'left'"

Comment: @MohammadAlamri . . . Your question is tagged MySQL and this function definitely exists in MySQL.  In Hive or MySQL, you can use `substr()`.

Comment: you're right, the second command works fine after I manipulated the numbers. Best answer. Thanks

Comment: @MohammadAlamri . . . Did you find a problem with this answer?  I noticed that you unaccepted it.

Comment: It didn't work perfectly, but it was a bit close. So I manipulated the number to get the perfect answer. you can find it as the chosen one.